# Angular: event.srcElement does not point on the expected Element

Tags: angular, events, click

To learn the basics of Angular I decided to write a little sudoku game. 
Here the html for the dynamicly build Sudoku grid:

```
<div
*ngIf="(this.sudokuGenerated && !this.sudokuSolved) || this.isEmptySudoku">
<table id="grid" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr class="grid-row" *ngFor="let row of this.displaySudoku.workingCopy; index as i;">
        <td #sudokucell class="grid-cell" *ngFor="let cell of row; index as j;" (click)="this.setNumberInCell(i, j, $event)">
            <span class="empty-cell" *ngIf="this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[i][j] == 0"> </span>
            <span class="empty-cell" *ngIf="this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[i][j] != 0 && this.displaySudoku.grid[i][j] == 0">{{cell}}</span> 
            <span class="given-cell" *ngIf="this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[i][j] != 0 && this.displaySudoku.grid[i][j] != 0">{{cell}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, there is a click event on every td. On click the following method is called. In the method the previous selected number is written in the selected cell (td). After inserting the number, the number gets checked against the sudoku solution. If wrong, the cell (td) gets a "wrong-cell" css class that change the background-color to red:

```
setNumberInCell(row: number, col: number, event: Event): void {
if (this.selectedNumber != null && !this.sudokuSolved && this.displaySudoku.grid[row][col] == 0) {
  this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[row][col] = this.selectedNumber;
  this.checkAndRenderErrorCell(row, col, this.selectedNumber, event.srcElement);
}
```

}

```
checkAndRenderErrorCell(row: number, col: number, nr: number, element: Element): void {
if (this.checkMode && element != undefined) {
  if (this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[row][col] != this.displaySudoku.solution[row][col]) {
    console.log(element);
    this.renderer.addClass(element, 'error-cell');
    this.renderer.removeClass(element, 'selected-cell');
  }
}
```

}

My problem is, that when I click on a cell and the srcElement is fetched from the event, I always get the wrong Element.
For Example: When I click on Cell 0 (row 0 and column 0) I always get the td-Element with row-index 0 and cell-index 1. So when I put a wrong number into that cell, always the td-Element next to clicked one gets the red background color.
I tried a lot, but have no clue where I make the mistake.

Thanks a lot for your help!

*Update * I also tried event.target and event.currenTarget. But I still get the wrong Element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the element dispatching the event you should use the `$event.target` property.

```
setNumberInCell(row: number, col: number, event: Event): void {
if (this.selectedNumber != null && !this.sudokuSolved && this.displaySudoku.grid[row][col] == 0) {
  this.displaySudoku.workingCopy[row][col] = this.selectedNumber;
  this.checkAndRenderErrorCell(row, col, this.selectedNumber, event.target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's the same result with target and currentTarget.